# How to get one number specific times in an array python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one array like `A = [1,2,3]` and another array `B = [4,5,6]`. Now, I need another array C so that the elements in C should be the same elements of B having occurrence in the order of element A. Like,
                       `C = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
C = [b_item for a_item, b_item in zip(A,B) for _ in range(a_item)]
print C
```

Result:

```
[4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

This is a one-line equivalent to:

```
C = []
for a_item, b_item in zip(A,B):
    for _ in range(a_item):
        C.append(b_item)
```

... Which is roughly equivalent to

```
C = []
for i in range(min(len(A), len(B))):
    a_item = A[i]
    b_item = B[i]
    for _ in range(a_item):
        C.append(b_item)
```

(N.B. Don't get tripped up by the underscore. [It's an ordinary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python). It is conventionally used when you don't actually have to refer to the variable's value, as in this example)

Comment: Could you explain this for the.. less pythonic inclined people like me? I was thinking 2 for loops lol

Comment: @SterlingArcher, sure. In a way, I _am_ using two for loops. I just crammed both of them into one expression.

Comment: Thanks. But as Sterling Archer told .... is there any simple logic to do this? Although, this works.

Answer (score 6):

I will provide another way of doing it, using a different idea (not claiming he should use this, but for didactic reasons)

I find pretty neat to be able to replicate elements in python using

```
[0]*3 # it means we create 3 elements of zero: [0,0,0]
```

if I simply do this:

```
[[x]*i for i,x in zip(A, B)]
```

I get groups of elements:

```
[[4], [5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]
```

Then, we could use itertools.chain to get back to a single list:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[[x]*i for i,x in zip(A, B)]))
[4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution using numpy:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array = [1,2,3]
b = numpy.array = [4,5,6]

c = numpy.repeat(b,a)
```

Result:

```
array([4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
```

Here more information about using numpy.repeat : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
C = sum([[B[i]]*A[i] for i in range(len(A))], [])
print C
```

Explaination:

`[B[i]]*A[i]` will create a list with `A[i]` items of `B[i]`

`[B[i]]*A[i] for i in range(len(A))]` will give you a list of lists, eg `[[4], [5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]`

`sum(C, [])` will convert list of lists into list

Comment: Yep, this works. `sum(sequence, [])` is a little inefficient memory-wise since it has to create multiple intermediary lists, but that's not a big deal if C is reasonably small.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
C = []
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    C.extend([b] * a)
```

But I'd prefer the list comprehension, just without the annoying `_item`, i.e.,

```
C = [b for a, b in zip(A, B) for _ in range(a)]
```

Or the shorter (but for large cases slow) sum:

```
C = sum(([b] * a for a, b in zip(A, B)), [])
```